# Start app from commandline and return version info

Tags: vb.net, command-line-arguments

I am developing an application that will run with a GUI when no commandline args are passed, but can also run invisibly if started from the commandline and passed necessary arguments. I have been asked to include a `/version` argument that will return a version number. For simplicity this version number can be stored in a variable. Without doing something like writing the version number out to a file, what is the best way for me to return this info to the caller? My app will almost always be started from a script, so the script will have to read the version number and make decisons based on the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Google gave me this, should do what you want? [reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/70364db9-ae2c-4ea8-9cb1-7df4fd89d486)</strike>

If you want to return a value to the caller, you can do change your main() method signature to return an integer instead.

```
Function Main() As Integer
```

Note that you can only return an int. If you want something like "1.0.2" you can either come up with a scheme for the numbering (like padding with zeroes etc) or encode it in some way, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks but no. "For simplicity this version number can be stored in a variable." Plus, your Google search taught you had to GET the version info. That wasn't my question. I asked for the best way to return the version info to the script that started the app.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread it as you didn't want to store a version number anywhere, but obviously that was not what you meant. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was either going to make Main() a function or use Environment.Exit(version)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i am on the move with the ipad, so i cannot do anny testing, but could you not include console, then use console.writeLine(versionstring)

This example from about.com  http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/CmdLine_3.htm